# Dog keeps mouthing and barking at me

Tags: vocalizations

When my boyfriend leaves the house his very large male German Shepard barks excessively at me.  And has started mouthing me now.  He has broken the skin a few times and it seems to be getting worse. Why does he do this and how do we get it to stop.  I am not wanting to stay there anymore.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Is the dog doing this, since you first time were alone with him? Or changed his behavior only in last time?

Comment: What have you tried to make him stop?

Comment: What kind of mouthing does he do? Does it look like biting but he only nips you instead of a real bite? Or does he take your whole hand or arm into his mouth and sometimes is too rough? Please [edit] your post to add more details.